# Is C#'s yield return thread safe with a Custom IEnumerator?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, yield-return

I have a simple concept of a customized IEnumerator class providing an enumeration of struct/value types.  (int, datetime, enum, etc)

```
class MyNumer : IEnumerator<int>
{
   public MyNumer(int start, int end) { _start = start; _end = end; }
   int _start;
   int _end;

   //Please just assume i've implemented the rest of IEnumerator, this is the only element that is 
   //pertinent to the question

   public bool MoveNext()
   {
      if (this.Current == 0) this.Current = _start;
      else if (this.Current <= _end) this.Current++;
      return this.Current <= _end;
   }
}

class ThreadedClass
{
   public IEnumerable<int> GetNumbers(int start, int end)  //this method can be called from multiple threads
   {
      IEnumerator<int> numer = new MyNumer(start, end);
      while (numer.MoveNext()) yield return numer.Current;
   }
}
```

What I'm concerned about is provided this example, if :

1. Thread1 calls "myThreadedClass.GetNumbers(1, 10)"
2. Thread2 calls "myThreadedClass.GetNumbers(30, 40)"
3. Thread3 calls "myThreadedClass.GetNumbers(70, 100)"

Will I get three separate, distinct IEnumerable returned, or will the threads collide on the "yield return"?

Comment: Did you try to run it and see what happens?

Comment: Also, the first result from google [Is yield return in C# thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379266/is-yield-return-in-c-sharp-thread-safe)

Comment: Each thread has it's own stack, so yeah. There will be no collision.

Comment: The real problem is if someone passes in a value <= 0 for start and >0 for end and then you have an infinite loop

Comment: juharr - absolutely, that's all controlled in the constructor, so i wasn't concerned about that.  I was just curious whether or not "yield return" would be thread safe in this circumstance, and it appears Andy (and Theodor below) answered that.  Pavel - if you look at that link it isn't about this question.  That is a poorly titled post, since that coder's issue is not about threading, but proper use of enumerables, since he is changing the collection after the enumerator is created.  There is no collection, this is a custom enumerator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only you will get three distinct `IEnumerable<int>` objects, but also each time you enumerate each of them a new `IEnumerator<int>` will be created, with its own distinct internal instance of the `MyNumer` class. So there would be no thread safety issue even if all three threads were sharing the same `IEnumerable<int>` instance, returned by a single invocation of the `GetNumbers` method.

Comment: This is what i thought, but figured a second opinion would be helpful.